# How to add External Website Link in Bottom Navbar Android Studio

Tags: android, html, android-studio

I am Fresher and Don't Know How to add External Website link in Bottom Navbar that work on app without leaving App.

Suppose i want to Add this 3 tab on Bottom Navbar Below is Example.

```
                                           Home    Shop    Game
```

I want here in "Home" Section its default homepage of App

In "SHOP" section i want to add my website link that show on app as a browser without leaving app.

& In last "GAME" Section I want also add here External link that link will open in app.

So Please Suggest me code that work for me..

Your help will highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this is quite easy.
Add a WebView in your app through XML and initialize in onCreate().
For implementing the above, you can declare TextViews in the bottom navigation bar in XML, setting their text to whatever you want to be written in the button.
Then, initialize them in your onCreate() method of the activity like this:-

```
TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.<nameofview>);
WebView web = findViewbyId(R.id.<name>);
```

Then, in the onCreate() method itself, you can set onClickListeners on the TextViews to open the link when it is clicked.
Something like:-

```
t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
web.loadUrl("your URL of webpage");
}
});
```

Note:- The above code is for only one of your TextViews, you have to do this for all three of them.

Comment: Thanks for answer but Sir I don't want to open in external browser its should open app only. how to do it ?

Comment: Ok. Then, use a WebView in your app.

Comment: Read more about implementing WebView here:-https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview